# Posterior Distribution Decaying to Zero (Underflow Problem)

Tags: r, bayesian, prior

Say I have a coin. I have no information about this coin; I have no reason believe that it's $p = 0.5$, or anything else, for that matter.

So, I use a uniform prior:

```
rangeP <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 10000)
prior <- dunif(rangeP)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Prior]

Now, I perform an experiment (n = 1 249 104), and I get k = 928 235 heads.

The likelihood of this, will then be:

```
likelihood <- dbinom(x = 928235, rangeP, size = 1249104)
```

Thus, for every value of $p$, we have the likelihood of having observed the data. Plotting the likelihood:

[image: Likelihood]

There is a small spike at the maximum likelihood estimator (0.7431207).

Zooming into this spike a little:

[image: Zoomed In]

The problem is now a computational one; for the likelihood, everywhere besides the spike is 0 (actually very close to 0, but my computer doesn't think so).

So when I try calculate the posterior, I get values of zero everywhere besides where the little spike is:

```
unstdPost <- prior * likelihood
stdPost <- unstdPost / sum(unstdPost)
```

(unstdPost for unstandardized posterior, stdPost for standardized).

Finally, the posterior looks as follows:

[image: Posterior]

I now want to use this posterior as a new prior. Say I now change my coin: because of the zeroes, I can never "escape" this distribution.

I know I am supposed to use logs in calculating the likelihood in order to avoid this underflow problem, but I am not sure how to do so.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you change the coin, you certainly should not be using the posterior for the original coin as the prior for the new one unless you are absolutely sure that the coins have the same probability of heads - in which case you don't have a problem, really.

Comment: Although it does not change the gist of your question, the "normalization" disregards that the steps are $\frac{1}{10000}$ wide, not $1$. In other terms, $sum(stdPost)$ should give you $10000$, the same as $sum(prior)$ does, not $1$.

Comment: @jbowman is right: you should use that posterior as a prior only if you plan doing more experiments with the same coin. In this case, though, to avoid underflow errors you might just consider the total of heads you get and repeat the very same process you used in your example, and skip the double step with previous-posterior-as-current-prior.

Comment: There are a number of posts dealing with underflow and overflow problems and various tactics with the exp-sum-log approach to various calculations. If you search on (for example) *underflow* you may find some of them.

Comment: Sorry, the changing of coins was a bit contrived. The point is, for my actual use case, I need to do the update step (and not have my original posterior degrade to 0 in most places).